# Red frame for current date isn't showing

Tags: javascript, html, css

Calendar I created for my client is made so it shows the today's date with red frame around day number in current month. It worked normally until today when red frame is gone. It doesn't work only and only for 21.4. I tried to change date to whatever other day and red frame works just fine. Try yourself (ex. var novi_datum = new Date(2021, 7, 21)) work just fine.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    var novi_datum = new Date();
    var meseci = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];

    function getDaysInMonth(month, year) {
        var date = new Date(year, month);
        var days = [];
        while (date.getMonth() === month) {
            days.push(new Date(date));
            date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
        }
        return days;
    }
    function fill_calendar_table(month, year) {
        if (month != null) {
            $('#mesec').html(meseci[novi_datum.getMonth() + month] + ' ' + (novi_datum.getFullYear() + year));
            var dani = getDaysInMonth(novi_datum.getMonth() + month, novi_datum.getFullYear() + year);
        } else {
            $('#mesec').html(meseci[novi_datum.getMonth()] + ' ' + novi_datum.getFullYear());
            var dani = getDaysInMonth(novi_datum.getMonth(), novi_datum.getFullYear());
        }

        var jTrue = true;

        for (let i = 0; i < dani.length; i++) {
            if (jTrue) {
                var j = i;
                j += dani[i].getDay();
                for (let i = 0; i < $('#kalendar td').length; i++) {
                    $('#kalendar td')[i].innerHTML = '';
                }
                jTrue = false;
            }
            // Inserting dates into calendar
            $('#kalendar td')[j + 6].innerHTML = dani[i].getDate();

            // Adding red frame to current date
            if ($('#kalendar td')[i].innerText == novi_datum.getDate()
                && $('#mesec').text().includes(meseci[novi_datum.getMonth()])
                && $('#mesec').text().includes(novi_datum.getFullYear())) {
                $('#kalendar td')[i].style.border = '1px solid red';
            } else {
                $('#kalendar td')[i].style.border = 'none';
            }

            j++;
        }
        var empty_rows = document.querySelectorAll('.last_two_rows');
        empty_rows.forEach(function (red) {
            if (red.children[0].innerHTML == '') {
                red.style.display = 'none';
            } else {
                red.style.display = 'table-row';
            }
        })

        if ($('#kalendar td')[6].innerHTML != '') {
            $('.red')[0].style.display = 'table-row';
        } else {
            $('.red')[0].style.display = 'none';
        }

    }
    fill_calendar_table();

    var month_increment = 0;
    var year_increment = 0;
    $('#novi_mesec').on('click', function () {
        if ($('#mesec').html().includes(meseci[11])) {
            month_increment -= month_increment + novi_datum.getMonth() + 1;
            year_increment++;
        }
        month_increment++;
        fill_calendar_table(month_increment, year_increment);
    })

    $('#prethodni_mesec').on('click', function () {
        if ($('#mesec').html().includes(meseci[0])) {
            month_increment += 12;
            year_increment--;
        }

        month_increment--;
        fill_calendar_table(month_increment, year_increment);
    }
    )
})
```

```css
#kalendar{
    margin: 20px auto;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    border-spacing: 10px;
    border-collapse: separate;
    font-size: 15px;
}
#kalendar td, th{
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
#naslov{
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 900;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
}
.red:first-of-type{
    display: none;
}
#mesec{
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
}
.arrows{
    font-size: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
}
.arrow_parent{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}
.righ_arrow{
    margin-left: 50px;
}
.left_arrow{
    margin-right: 50px;
}
td{
    cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="calendar_parent">
    <table id="kalendar">
        <caption id="mesec"></caption>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>m</th>
                <th>t</th>
                <th>w</th>
                <th>t</th>
                <th>f</th>
                <th>s</th>
                <th>s</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="red">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="red">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="red">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="red">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="red">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="red last_two_rows">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="red last_two_rows">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="arrow_parent">
        <div id="prethodni_mesec" class="arrows left_arrow">&laquo;</div>
        <div id="novi_mesec" class="arrows righ_arrow">&raquo;</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It appears to be working from `new Date(2021, 5, 1)` on only, _anything_ below does not work, in my tests.

Comment: In my tests, it seems too that it worked only until yesterday : 2021,3,20 OK, 2021,3,21 nok, 2021,3,22 nok,... etc and yes @CBroe, it seems that it works again from 2021,5,1 on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact that the days are not at always at the same place, depending on the month's structure. If one day is too "far" (empty `td`s at the beginning of the month), you don't reach them. I've separated the day's detection from the month's structuration in you code :

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    var novi_datum = new Date();
    var meseci = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];

    function getDaysInMonth(month, year) {
        var date = new Date(year, month);
        var days = [];
        while (date.getMonth() === month) {
            days.push(new Date(date));
            date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
        }
        return days;
    }
    function fill_calendar_table(month, year) {
        if (month != null) {
            $('#mesec').html(meseci[novi_datum.getMonth() + month] + ' ' + (novi_datum.getFullYear() + year));
            var dani = getDaysInMonth(novi_datum.getMonth() + month, novi_datum.getFullYear() + year);
        } else {
            $('#mesec').html(meseci[novi_datum.getMonth()] + ' ' + novi_datum.getFullYear());
            var dani = getDaysInMonth(novi_datum.getMonth(), novi_datum.getFullYear());
        }

        var jTrue = true;

        for (let i = 0; i < dani.length; i++) {
            if (jTrue) {
                var j = i;
                j += dani[i].getDay();
                for (let i = 0; i < $('#kalendar td').length; i++) {
                    $('#kalendar td')[i].innerHTML = '';
                }
                jTrue = false;
            }
            // Inserting dates into calendar
            $('#kalendar td')[j + 6].innerHTML = dani[i].getDate();

         
            j++;
        }

            let day_matched=false;
            let day=0;
            while(!day_matched) {
                if ($('#kalendar td')[day].innerText == novi_datum.getDate()
                    && $('#mesec').text().includes(meseci[novi_datum.getMonth()])
                    && $('#mesec').text().includes(novi_datum.getFullYear())) {
                    $('#kalendar td')[day].style.border = '1px solid red';
                    day_matched = true;
                } else {
                    $('#kalendar td')[day].style.border = 'none';
                }
                day++;
            }

        var empty_rows = document.querySelectorAll('.last_two_rows');
        empty_rows.forEach(function (red) {
            if (red.children[0].innerHTML == '') {
                red.style.display = 'none';
            } else {
                red.style.display = 'table-row';
            }
        })

        if ($('#kalendar td')[6].innerHTML != '') {
            $('.red')[0].style.display = 'table-row';
        } else {
            $('.red')[0].style.display = 'none';
        }

    }
    fill_calendar_table();

    var month_increment = 0;
    var year_increment = 0;
    $('#novi_mesec').on('click', function () {
        if ($('#mesec').html().includes(meseci[11])) {
            month_increment -= month_increment + novi_datum.getMonth() + 1;
            year_increment++;
        }
        month_increment++;
        fill_calendar_table(month_increment, year_increment);
    })

    $('#prethodni_mesec').on('click', function () {
        if ($('#mesec').html().includes(meseci[0])) {
            month_increment += 12;
            year_increment--;
        }

        month_increment--;
        fill_calendar_table(month_increment, year_increment);
    }
    )
})
```

```css
#kalendar{
    margin: 20px auto;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    border-spacing: 10px;
    border-collapse: separate;
    font-size: 15px;
}
#kalendar td, th{
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
#naslov{
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 900;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
}
.red:first-of-type{
    display: none;
}
#mesec{
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
}
.arrows{
    font-size: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
}
.arrow_parent{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}
.righ_arrow{
    margin-left: 50px;
}
.left_arrow{
    margin-right: 50px;
}
td{
    cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="calendar_parent">
    <table id="kalendar">
        <caption id="mesec"></caption>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>m</th>
                <th>t</th>
                <th>w</th>
                <th>t</th>
                <th>f</th>
                <th>s</th>
                <th>s</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="red">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="red">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="red">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="red">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="red">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="red last_two_rows">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="red last_two_rows">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="arrow_parent">
        <div id="prethodni_mesec" class="arrows left_arrow">&laquo;</div>
        <div id="novi_mesec" class="arrows righ_arrow">&raquo;</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That was the exact problem. Thank you